# RSpecでエラーを発生させたいのにnothing was raisedと出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

システムをrubyのバージョンをアップ（ruby 1.9.2p320⇒2.2.3）しました。Railsのバージョンは3.2.19 DBはMySQLを使用しています。
テストを実行したところエラーが発生し以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Failures:

  1) …の場合は、 そのまま例外をraiseする。
     Failure/Error: lambda{Job.find_by_id(@conn, 0)}.should raise_error(ex)
       expected Unauthorized but nothing was raised
```

プロダクトコードは以下のようでテストでmrqを実行したときに任意のエラーを発生させようとしてます。

```
def self.find_by_id(conn, id)
  options = {…}
  response = Job.mrq(conn, options)
```

テストコードです。

```
before(:each) do
  Job.should_receive(:mrq).and_raise(ex)
end
context "…の場合は、" do
  let(:ex){SomeError.new("Unauthorized", 401)}
  it "そのまま例外をraiseする。" do
    lambda{Job.find_by_id(@conn, 0)}.should raise_error(ex)
  end
end
```

rspec (2.11.0)を使用してます。ruby 1.9.2では動作していました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ドキュメントに書いてあるように、`raise_error`マッチャ―の引数に渡すのは例外クラスです。例外クラスのインスタンスではありません。
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

以下のように、`SomeError`クラスを渡すようにすると通ると思います。

```
lambda{Job.find_by_id(@conn, 0)}.should raise_error(SomeError)
```

より詳しく例外オブジェクトについて検証したいのであれば、ブロックを渡して検証するといいです。

```
lambda{Job.find_by_id(@conn, 0)}.should raise_error(SomeError) {|e| e.should eq ex }
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher#set-expectations-on-error-object-passed-to-block

### なぜRubyのバージョンを上げて落ちるようになったか

内部の実装的には、`raise_error`マッチャーの引数に渡した値が`rescue`節に渡ります。
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/v2.11.0/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/raise_error.rb#L23

以下のように、`rescue`に例外クラスのインスタンスを渡すようなプログラムが、Ruby 1.9.2では実行出来るが、Ruby 2.2.3では実行できなくなったため、バージョンアップで落ちるようになったのではないでしょうか。

```
class FooError < StandardError; end
bar = FooError.new
begin; raise bar; rescue bar => e; p e; end
```

Comment: クラスを直接渡すようにしたら上手くいってたのですが理由が分かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

本当にRubyのバージョンアップがテスト失敗の原因なのでしょうか？
テストコードも本番コードも変更していないのに、バージョンアップ後にテストが失敗するようになったのでしょうか？

とりあえず、コードを見たところ `mrq` にスタブを当てているのに、テストコードの中では `find_by_id` が呼ばれているように見えます。

正しくはこうなるのではないでしょうか？

```
before(:each) do
  Job.should_receive(:mrq).and_raise(ex)
end
context "…の場合は、" do
  let(:ex){SomeError.new("Unauthorized", 401)}
  it "そのまま例外をraiseする。" do
    # find_by_id => mrq
    lambda{Job.mrq(@conn, 0)}.should raise_error(ex)
  end
end
```

### 追記

以下のように書くと結果はどうなりますか？

```
context "…の場合は、" do
  let(:ex){SomeError.new("Unauthorized", 401)}
  it "そのまま例外をraiseする。" do
    Job.should_receive(:mrq).and_raise(ex)
    Job.find_by_id(@conn, 0)
  end
end
```

`:mrq`が呼ばれなかったという理由でFailするようであれば、そもそもfind_by_idでJob.mrqが呼ばれるようなフローになっていないのかもしれません。（意図しない条件分岐に入ってしまっている等）

また、find_by_idの実装を以下のように極端にシンプルに変えると確実にスタブが呼ばれてエラーが発生する、つまりテストがパスするはずです。これも試してみてください。

```
def self.find_by_id(conn, id)
  Job.mrq(conn, nil)
end
```

このように、「エラーの原因の仮説を立てる」「仮説が正しいことを検証できるコードを書く」「結果を確認する」「期待した結果が得られない（＝仮説が間違っていた）場合は別の仮説を立てる」「コードを書いて実行する」・・・（以下繰り返し）、というような「当たり前のデバッグ手順」を踏んで原因を絞り込んでいくしかないかなーという気がします。
また、デバッガを使ってステップ実行していくのも有効でしょう。

質問で書かれているコード自体は大きな問題がないように見えます。

Comment: すみません。プロダクトコートの記述が不十分でした。書き直しました。　　
find_by_idの中のmrq でエラーを発生させようとしてます。  
コードは変更しておらずバージョンアップだけでエラーになっています。

Comment: 追記では上手くいきませんでした。2番目の回答で上手くいきました。アドバイスありがとうございます。デバッガを使っていきたいです。